# Swift avspeechsynthesizer different languages

Tags: swift, xcode6, avspeechsynthesizer

```
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-au"];
```

This exact line of code is how you can change the languages in obj-c. But i was wondering if anyone, could tell me how so it is implemented in swift. in documentation this line of code is used...

```
init!(language language: String!) -> AVSpeechSynthesisVoice
```

But i can't understand where i would implement it :/

Comment: So the problem has nothing to do with AVSpeechSynthesisVoice, right? The problem is that you don't know Swift so you don't understand how to call an initializer? That is, what you're really asking is: please translate this line of code from Objective-C to Swift for me? Are you going to do that for every line of Objective-C code in the world, or are you going to learn to do this for yourself? Here are the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306

Answer (score 2):

Where you see `init(paramName: ParamType)` in the Swift interface for a type named `Type`, you call it with the syntax `Type(paramName: paramValue)`. This is right at the top of the chapter on [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306) in *The Swift Programming Language*, which I'd recommend reading before getting more than trivially into Cocoa development with Swift.

Also worth reading is the section on [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*, which repeats the above and also gives you the general rule for how ObjC initializers and factory methods automatically map to Swift initializers: if you have a ObjC class named `Foo` with the initializer `initWithBar:` and/or the factory class method `fooWithBar:`, it maps to the Swift initializer `init(bar:)` and you call it with the syntax `Foo(bar: someBarValue)`.

So:

```
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-au") // g'day, mate
```

Note that this specific initializer is of the form `init!` — that means that the underlying ObjC code can return nil, and that Swift wraps the result of the initializer call in an [Implicitly Unwrapped Optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496). Since `AVSpeechUtterance.voice` can accept an optional (including one with a nil value), you're in the clear. But if that ever changes, or if you need to deal with APIs that explicitly require a non-nil voice, you should check that optional; e.g.:

```
if let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-au") {
    // do something with voice
} else {
    // pick another one, maybe?
}
```

Comment: To change speak language using  "en" instead of  "en-au" is enough I think.